# Is there a complete Freebase dump available that also includes the schema?

Tags: freebase, mql

Is there any Freebase dump that includes all the data along with the schema as well? It should have the complete Freebase data as if it was deployed inside Metaweb. Is there any dump that is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quad dump includes the schema:

```
$ bzgrep $'/type/object/type\t/type/type' freebase-datadump-quadruples.tsv.bz2
/m/01xxrl4      /type/object/type       /type/type
/m/01xxwk6      /type/object/type       /type/type
/m/01y1zzx      /type/object/type       /type/type
/m/021_hyv      /type/object/type       /type/type
/m/0252jv4      /type/object/type       /type/type
/m/0252jw2      /type/object/type       /type/type
/m/0252jx0      /type/object/type       /type/type
/m/025dnqw      /type/object/type       /type/type
/m/0290pj9      /type/object/type       /type/type
```

It's available from http://download.freebase.com/datadumps/latest/freebase-datadump-quadruples.tsv.bz2

Comment: Thanks Tom. I did see this. So is this quad dump a complete footprint of the Freebase that is also queried when we execute MQL queries in the online freebase editor?

Comment: No, it's not identical.  It's missing all edit dates & attribution information, at least.  A more important question is does it have what you need.  What are you looking for?